# Optimizing class layout by minimizing padding safely

Tags: c++, layout, language-lawyer, type-alias

I have the following type and my goal is to optimize the size of `Storage`:

```cpp
struct Inlined   { int  data[9];              };            // sizeof => 36
struct Allocated { int* data; size_t capacity };            // sizeof => 16
union  Data      { Inlined inlined; Allocated allocated; }; // sizeof => 40

struct Storage {                                            // sizeof => 56
  size_t size;
  bool is_allocated;
  Data data;
};
```

I understand that sizes and layout may vary between compilers and platforms. My goal is to get more compact layout on at least some compilers/platforms.

As you can see in my example, `Data` has 4 bytes of padding because `Inlined` and `Allocated` have different alignments and `Data` is 8-byte aligned. I am trying to find a way to squeeze boolean `is_allocated` into this padding.

So far, I came up with the following structure and I would really appreciate if someone can confirm or deny "safety" / "legalness" of such type:

```cpp
struct CompactStorage {                                      // sizeof => 48
  size_t size;
  union {
    struct {
      bool is_allocated;
      Inlined inlined;
    };
    struct {
      bool copy_of_is_allocated;
      Allocated allocated;
    };
  };
};
```

To clarify, by safety I mean that I expect `CompactStorage::is_allocated` and `CompactStorage::copy_of_is_allocated` to be aliasing the same memory. And I expect that if I write to `CompactStorage::is_allocated` then it does not overwrite bytes aliased by `CompactStorage::allocated` (and vice versa). If that does not hold, then I consider `CompactStorage` unsafe as it cannot be used as a replacement for `Storage`.

P.S. I know about bitfields and deliberately do not use them due to (proven) performance implications.

Comment: are you sure about those sizeofs? wouldn't Data be at least 52?

Comment: @NeilButterworth no, it is a `union`, so the biggest member counts, which has `36` bytes, then align to the biggest data type, which is `8` bytes ==> `40`.

Comment: @mch oh god i missed that!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude

This is Abseil's InlinedVector (undercover). Right now, `size/is_allocated` are used as bitfields (sort of). This means that reading `InlinedVector::size` requires ~4 instructions. If I can optimize storage size without use of bitfields, then `size` reads/writes become noticeably faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much well-defined. From [[class.mem]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#general-26)

> In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type T1, it is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union member of struct type T2 provided m is part of the common initial sequence of T1 and T2; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of T1 were nominated.

Where [common initial sequence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem.general#23) is

> The common initial sequence of two standard-layout struct types is the longest sequence of non-static data members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first such entity in each of the structs, such that corresponding entities have layout-compatible types [...]

Which means you may use `is_allocated` and `copy_of_is_allocated` interchangeably, given that the structs are standard-layout types.

Comment: That's great! Thank you!
So I suppose if `Inlined` looks like this 

`template <typename T> struct Inlined {
    alignas(T) char inlined_data[sizeof(T[N])];
  };`

This still qualifies as a standard layout type, right?

Comment: @antonpp Yes. You should sanity check by sticking `static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Inlined>);` somewhere.

Comment: I think the anonymous struct is in extension territory. But assuming it behaves as expected™, nice answer.